# UPDATED: Express.js req.body is an empty object & req.body.name is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but I'm not getting anything from `req.body` or `req.body.name`.  I'm just trying to get text from an input field in a React component.  Here's my `POST` request:

```
    //posting notes to backend and storing in db
module.exports = (app,bodyparser,mongoUrl) => {


    let MongoDB = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
    app.use(bodyparser.json());

    app.post('/notes',function(req,res){
        //posting the note just fine, just not receiving the note text (says undefined)
        //not getting note text for some reason?? only returning the date...

        //send response to append note to page
        //store note data in db

        let noteData = {
            text: req.body.name,
            date: new Date().toDateString()
        };
        console.log(req.body);
        MongoDB.connect(mongoUrl,function(err,db){

                let notesCollection = db.collection('notes');
                notesCollection.insert(noteData);
                db.close();
        });

        res.status(201).send(noteData);

    });

}
```

And my React Component:

```
class NewNote extends Component {
//this is for creating a new note only
//need post request for this one
//need to clear textarea upon submit or cancel
    render(){
      return (
        <div id="form-container" className='container-fluid' style={defaultStyle}>
          <div id="form">
            <div className="form-group">
            <form action="/notes" method="POST" encType="multipart/form-data">
              <label htmlFor="newNote">New Note:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" className="form-control" rows="5" id="newNote" placeholder="Write your note here..."></input>
                <button id="done" type="submit" className="btn btn-primary pull-right">Done</button>
                <button id="cancel" className="btn btn-warning pull-right">Cancel</button>
            </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }

}
```

And my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "quick-notes-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "my first full-stack javascript app",
  "main": "./routes/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node ./routes/server.js --ignore public/",
    "dev": "webpack -wd",
    "lint": "eslint ./"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/CandiW/quick-notes-app.git"
  },
  "author": "CandiW",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/CandiW/quick-notes-app/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/CandiW/quick-notes-app#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.35",
    "randomcolor": "^0.5.3",
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.7.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.3",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

This is my `server.js` file where I've required the `body-parser` module:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const notes = require('./notes.js');
const myNotes = require('./mynotes.js');
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

let app = express();
let database = "mongodb://localhost:3000/";

    app.use(express.static('public'));
    app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
    app.use(bodyparser.json());

function quickNotesApp(port){
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log("listening on port " + port);

    notes(app,bodyparser,database);
    myNotes(app,bodyparser,database);

    app.listen(port);

}

quickNotesApp(3000);
```

Please excuse my comments in the code :) I'm using them to keep track of my to-do's and what each component does.  You all can see my github repo for my app here: [Quick-Notes-App](https://github.com/CandiW/Quick-Notes-App)

**Update 5/2/2018:**

I have made some changes to how I'm using `body-parser` and how I'm using it in my `POST` request (I've updated the original code samples I attached).  At this point, I'm still receiving the same `text: null` when I return the array of docs from my database and when I console.log `req.body` its still an empty object.  Wondering if anyone has any thoughts on if React.js is the issue?  For example, we have to use `className` instead of `class` in our React Components.  I'm not finding anything readily to answer that question.  I have also uninstalled and reinstalled express, body-parser, and all the rest of my dependencies to no avail.

**Update 2 - 5/2/2018**

For anyone who might find this useful, I found [this Medium article](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-combine-a-nodejs-back-end-with-a-reactjs-front-end-app-ea9b24715032) on how to combine a Node.js backend with a React.js frontend.  I think I'm going to try this out and see if it helps.

Comment: Can you please share your package.json

Comment: Sure - I'll edit the post here in a second

Comment: Can you please share also index.js of server side code.

Comment: It's there now!

Comment: you have to add `app.use(bodyParser.json());` like my below ans.

Comment: if not work let me know, thanks.

Comment: Thanks! I'll go try it out :)

Comment: I have given ans. below with your full index.js

Answer (score 0):

```
npm i --save body-parser
const body_parser = require('body-parser');
app.use(body_parser.json());
app.use(body_parser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

Comment: It'll be better if you add an explanation for why your code works.

Comment: i was using typescript and considered importing bodyParser like this and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Add this also `app.use(bodyParser.json());`

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const notes = require('./notes.js');
const myNotes = require('./mynotes.js');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

let app = express();
let database = "mongodb://localhost:3000/";
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyparser.json());

function quickNotesApp(port){
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log("listening on port " + port);
    app.use(express.static('public'));


    notes(app,database);
    myNotes(app,database);

    app.listen(port);

}

quickNotesApp(3000);
```

Comment: Ok - this didn't work.... Here's what it looks like in the database: `{"_id":"5ae872c5347b9e23901bf419","text":null,"date":"Tue May 01 2018"}`  As you can see, the `text` is `null`.

Comment: I have made some changes and edited my original question to reflect those updates.  In short, I'm still receiving the same `"text": null`.